# How can I get the java.util.Date value from PL/SQL typed TIMESTAMP(9) WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE using oracle.sql.Datum

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I coded a function in PL/SQL that returns a coder-defined object "OBJ_FRIEND".
PL/SQL code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_FRIEND IS OBJECT(
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
BIRTHDATE TIMESTAMP(9) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
);
/
```

And retrieved it in Java.
Java code

```
...
Datum[] datums=oracleCallableStatement.getSTRUCT(1).getOracleAttributes();
Date date=datums[2].dateValue(); //I tried timestampValue also but didn't work.
```

How can I get a java.util.Date value from the datum object?

Comment: What does mean "don't work"?

Comment: The error say "Conversion to timestamp failed."

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What is in *datums* variable? Can't it be *null*?

Comment: It cant be null. The datums variable is the object I created in PL/SQL, the "OBJ_FRIEND". I want to get the BIRTHDATE field which is in index 2.

Comment: When I SELECT from the table, the first row of the BIRTHDATE field returns "16-SEP-90 08.00.00.000000000 AM"

Comment: What do you get when you try eg.  `for (Datum d: datums){ System.err.println(d.toJdbc());}`

Comment: Wow! It resulted to nulls. Maybe the "TIMESTAMP(9) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE" is really not supported. I just changed the type to "TIMESTAMP(9)" and it worked.